# Pandas variable shifting within groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
c1   Lag  Val1  
A    3    10
A    1    5
A    2    20
A    2    15
A    1    10
B    1    25
B    2    10
```

I want to create a new field val2 such that each value in val2 is the value in val2 shifted by Lag number of rows. The tricky part here is that the shift should happen within the groups defined in field c1, such that the output looks something like

```
c1   Lag  Val1  Val2
A    3    10    15
A    1    5     20
A    2    20    10
A    2    15    NaN
A    1    10    NaN
B    1    25    10
B    2    10    NaN
```

I have been trying with along the lines of

```
df['Val2'] = df.groupby(['c1'])['Val1'].apply(lambda x:x.shift(df.Lag))
```

to no avail and getting a "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous." error. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can can accomplish this with self-`merge` and a little manipulation of the index:

```
# Copy and keep only the columns that are relevant
df2 = df.rename(columns={'Val1': 'Val2'}).drop(columns='Lag').copy()

# Shift the index
df.index = df.index+df.Lag

# Merge, requiring match on shifted index and within group.
df.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['index', 'c1'], how='left').drop(columns='index')
```

#### Output:

```
  c1  Lag  Val1  Val2
0  A    3    10  15.0
1  A    1     5  20.0
2  A    2    20  10.0
3  A    2    15   NaN
4  A    1    10   NaN
5  B    1    25  10.0
6  B    2    10   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely have to write your own function for the apply. Something like this would work, but theres probably a more efficient way than iterating rows and repeatedly calculating row shifts...

```
def shift_rows(g):
    g['Val2'] = np.nan
    for i,r in g.iterrows():
        g.at[i, 'Val2'] = g['Val1'].shift(-r['Lag'])[i]
    return g

output = df.groupby('c1').apply(shift_rows)
print(output)

  c1  Lag  Val1  Val2
0  A    3    10  15.0
1  A    1     5  20.0
2  A    2    20  10.0
3  A    2    15   NaN
4  A    1    10   NaN
5  B    1    25  10.0
6  B    2    10   NaN
```

The idea is to iterate through each row of the groupby object to calculate a row shift using the value in `Lag`, then pull out the new value you want. This gets stored into `Val2` for that row and the whole group gets returned